# Issue with sending mails from grafana

Tags: grafana

I am trying to send mails from grafana but getting below error.

t=2017-12-22T07:24:46+0000 lvl=eror msg="Failed to send alert notifications" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin error="534 5.7.14  Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 j27sm22594347eda.59 - gsmtp"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check [smtp] section of __grafana.ini__ config file and confirm that the SMTP configuration there is set correctly. This file is in `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`

Comment: Here is my smtp config...[smtp]
enabled = true
host = smtp.gmail.com:587
user = xxxx
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with trippel quotes. Ex """#password;"""
password = yyyy
;cert_file =
;key_file =
skip_verify = true
from_address = xxxx
from_name = Grafana
# EHLO identity in SMTP dialog (defaults to instance_name)
;ehlo_identity = dashboard.example.com

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same error while trying to send mail alert to a gmail account. 
Enabling IMAP in the Gmail settings and enabling 'allow less secure apps to access your account' option fixed the issue for me.

The details on how to enable the two options mentioned above are present in the link provided in the error log: 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636650859449850569-2622875240&rd=2#cantsignin

Adding details from the link as suggested:

1) Set up IMAP : Check that IMAP is turned on

```
On your computer, open Gmail.
In the top right, click Settings Settings.
Click Settings.
Click the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab.
In the "IMAP Access" section, select Enable IMAP.
Click Save Changes.
```

2) Enabling 'allow less secure apps to access your account'

Change your settings to allow less secure apps into your account. We don't recommend this option because it can make it easier for someone to break into your account. If you want to allow access anyway, follow these steps:

```
Go to the Less secure apps section of your Google Account.
Turn on Allow less secure apps. If you don't see this setting, your administrator might have turned off less secure app account access.
```

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Answer (score 0):

I initially struggled a lot with this issue.
The solution is simple.
Enabling 'allow less secure apps to access your account' solves the problem.
Also make sure to not have 2 factor authentication.